# Could not load file or assembly Devart.Data

Tags: sqlite, devart

I have such issue. 
On my PC where VS is installed and project is developing I use `Devart linqconnect`.

I set option "Copy Local" for `Devart.Data.Linq`, `Devart.Data.SQLite` and `Devart.Data.SQLite.Linq` to `true`. All goes OK.

When try to run application on client side error `Could not load file or assembly 'Devart.Data, Version=5.0.828.0 ...` appears. What can be solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also necessary to add the Devart.Data assembly of the corresponding version to your project and set Copy Local for it to True.

To deploy applications written with the help of LinqConnect you should register run-time assemblies Devart.Data.SQLite.dll, Devart.Data.dll,  Devart.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll and Devart.Data.Linq.dll at Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or place them to the bin folder of your application.

JIC: these assemblies can be found in the folder where LinqConnect is installed.

Comment: I have two version of the same project, the newer one, which uses never version of sqlite builds fine, but the old version is having the same error that have been posted. Devart.Data is referenced, and because the new version build I assume the needed assemblies are already registered in the GAC, or do I need to register the old versions as well?

Comment: I've added devart.data.dll and devart.data.sqlite.dll to the GAC, do I need to ad the linq dlls as well even if I'm not using LinqConnect?